# How to connect database from file in view folder with codeIgniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

In code igniter, you can connect database and make queries in controller like:

```
$this->db->query(Your query);
$this->db->get();
```

How can I connect database from file in view folder?Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you shouldn't.

Even in a view file, `$this` still refers to the current controller so `$this->db->get('my_table')` will work exactly the same as it would in the controller.

However, as surely you must have heard, it's recommended to pass variables to the view from the controller instead of preforming non view-related tasks in the view file itself, and doing database manipulation (getting data, updating, deleting, etc.) in the model layer. This is one of the fundaments of MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of MVC (Model, View, Controller) is to segregate concerns. It is not the view's **job** to handle database queries. That should be strictly handled in your model. Instead write the query in your model and have your controller return it to your view.